# How to copy file from EC2 to local machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How to copy a file or folder from EC2 instance? I want to download a file from my server but I don't have idea how to do it.

P.S. I know how to copy in EC2.

Comment: Windows or Linux EC2 instance?

Comment: You need to use an ssh client. There are other ways too

Comment: I have used sudo scp -i and it works for me . Thanks all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `scp` to securely copy a file from your EC2 instance to your local machine. You will need three things:

1. Your `ec2key.pem` key -- You created this when you created the EC2 instance
2. Your EC2 username and IP -- You can find this in the EC2 Console ('Connect to Instance' button)
3. Path to your file

On your local machine, open up your command line, and type:

```
scp -i ec2key.pem username@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:/path/to/file .
```

Note that the period at the end signifies that the file is to be saved 'here'.

Comment: is it possible to achieve this from within the containers, if you have ssh'd into the server already?